# A “math word” problem - "catch per hour for each kilometer"

Tags: word-problem

Thank you for your time. Please take a look at an LSAT sentence below:

> THE CPUE, i.e. "catch per unit effort," for any species of shark is
> the number of those sharks that commercial fishing boats catch per
> hour for each kilometer of gill net set out in the water.

So I am confused by how a calculation for a CPUE is done. I attempted to use faction to conceptualize it; "catch" is the numerator while "hour for each kilometer" is the denominator. However, I found it difficult to understand what "per hour for each kilometer" really means.

If the text were "per hour per kilometer", then I know I need to divide the numerator twice: first by hour, then by kilometer.

Yet, "per hour for each kilometer" seems to be more ambiguous. My intuition was to treat it as the same, but my understanding of English grammar made me cautious about this intuition.

Could anyone help explain what's the correct interpretation of the denominator?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: A common definition of the word **per** is "for each." I would just read the text as if it said "per hour per kilometer", because that's the reading that makes sense. Also, "for each kilometer" or even "per kilometer" does not combine with "per hour"; instead, "per hour" applies to "number of sharks" and then "per kilometer" applies to the entire phrase, "number of sharks per hour".

Comment: Let $x,y,z$ be arbitrary quantities. While the construction "x for each y per z" might give me pause the way you describe  [x for each (y per z) or (x for each y) per z?], I would read "x per y per z", "x for each y for each z" and "x per y for each z" as how David has explained.